# Sorting in XSLT1.0 for Special characters (space, /, etc)

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am facing a problem in XSLT1.0 sorting for spacial characters.I am doing sorting in XSLT on a specific field, say 'fundName' which have a value like 'fundname/A' and/or 'fundname A'. As per my understanding, sorting will be done based on ASCII value of each character and it should return in the order : 'fundname A', 'fundname/A'. But I am getting the value which has '/' first and then 'space' value.

The following is the code:

```
INPUT:
<fundList>
  <funds>
     <fundName>JNL/INSTITUTIONAL ALT 35</fundName>
     <fundCode>12</fundCode>
  </funds>  
  <funds>
     <fundName>JNL DISC MODERATE</fundName>
     <fundCode>15</fundCode>
  </funds>
  <funds>
     <fundName>JNL/WMC MONEY MARKET</fundName>
     <fundCode>10</fundCode>
  </funds>
</fundList>

XSLT:
<xsl:for-each select="fundList/funds">
  <xsl:sort select="fundName" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:sort select="fundCode" order="ascending" />

  <fundName><xsl:value-of select="fundName" /></fundName>
</xsl:for-each>

OUTPUT:
JNL/INSTITUTIONAL ALT 35
JNL/WMC MONEY MARKET
JNL DISC MODERATE
```

NOTE: But, I have tried this in online, it's giving correct repsonse (First space and then /).

Answer (score 0):

Sorting order is dependent on which XSLT processor you are using, so it's entirely to be expected that different processors give you different results. Some processors may sort according to the Unicode (or ASCII) code value, but there's no guarantee of this: very often, processors will attempt a more intelligent sort, such as you find in the index of a book; and it may well depend on your language choices at the operating system level.

If you want more precise control you need to look at the documentation for your specific processor, but you may be able to achieve what you want by using the translate() function to convert the sort key to a different value that sorts the way you desire.